# python dbf query with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dbf

I am using [dbf](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/) strong text module in my projects.

my dbf file condtains 5 fields. (ACKNO is primary key field)

ACKNO   INVNO   INVDT  CTYPE  DTYPE

Read DBF is working file and querying single field (using .index_search)is working fine

Now I have **problem with querying multiple fields with multiple conditions**.

I tried with with List Comprehension, it is working, but slow with records with more than 2000 records

Currently i am converting my dbf table into pandas dataframe and using query with pandas dataframe.
Problem here is, it is very slow even for 1000 records also.

I would like to use dbf **index and index_search with multiple criteria using 1) query or 2) search or 3) index_search functions.**

My code is below

```
import dbf
import datetime
table = dbf.Table('inv.dbf', 'ACKNO N(12,0); INVNO N(8,0); INVDT D;  CTYPE C(1); DTYPE C(1);')
table.open(dbf.READ_WRITE)
for datum  in (
                (1000000001, 1001, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000002, 1002, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'G', 'D'),
                (1000000003, 1003, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'G', 'I'),
                (1000000004, 1004, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'A', 'C'),
                (1000000005, 1005, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'G', 'C'),
                (1000000006, 1006, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000007, 1007, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'G', 'D'),
                (1000000008, 1008, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 23), 'A', 'D'),
                (1000000009, 1009, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'G', 'I'),
                (1000000010, 1010, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'A', 'C'),
                (1000000011, 1011, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000012, 1012, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000013, 1013, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'N', 'D'),
                (1000000014, 1014, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 24), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000015, 1015, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 25), 'A', 'C'),
                (1000000016, 1016, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 25), 'G', 'I'),
                (1000000017, 1017, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 25), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000018, 1018, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 25), 'A', 'C'),
                (1000000019, 1019, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 25), 'A', 'D'),
                (1000000020, 1020, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'A', 'D'),
                (1000000021, 1021, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'G', 'I'),
                (1000000022, 1022, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'N', 'D'),
                (1000000023, 1023, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'A', 'I'),
                (1000000024, 1024, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'G', 'D'),
                (1000000025, 1025, dbf.Date(2023, 11, 26), 'N', 'I'),
                ):
    table.append(datum)

# I am using List Comprehension, it is working but slow with records with more than 2000 records
records = [rec for rec in table if (rec.INVDT == datetime.datetime.strptime('23-11-2023','%d-%m-%Y').date())
           & (rec.CTYPE == "A") & (rec.DTYPE == "I")]

for row in records:                    
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
    
table.close()
```

Comment: Pandas can be used directly to filter /select rows meeting your conditions and should be **much** faster than you indicate - fractions of a second for thousands of rows in my test using your data. It would be useful to see your Pandas code including that forming the DF.

Comment: Here number of records are 25, it is working fast, when i checked records with 4000, it was slow

Comment: I extended your data to 4000 records and Pandas selected using your conditions in a few milliseconds. It must be your code, maybe the conversion to DF which is so slow. But without seeing details I can't see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`create_index`](https://github.com/ethanfurman/dbf/blob/150e905134a1c00b85a60d7cf77774df032694b5/dbf/tables.py#L3863) then make a [`search`](https://github.com/ethanfurman/dbf/blob/150e905134a1c00b85a60d7cf77774df032694b5/dbf/_index.py#L166) to match the  three criterias :

```
from dbf import Table
import datetime

with Table("inv.dbf") as table:

    idx = table.create_index(key=lambda rec: (rec.INVDT, rec.CTYPE, rec.DTYPE))

    records = idx.search(match=(datetime.date(2023, 11, 23), "A", "I"))
```

Output :

```
for rec in records:
    print(*rec, sep=" "*3)

1000000001   1001   2023-11-23   A   I
1000000006   1006   2023-11-23   A   I
```

Alternatively, you can use [geopandas](/questions/tagged/geopandas) to load the (`.dbf`) file, then make a [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) :

```
# pip install geopandas
import geopandas as gpd

table = gpd.read_file("inv.dbf").iloc[:, :-1]

res = table.query("INVDT == '2023-11-23' and CTYPE == 'A' and DTYPE == 'I'")

# print(res.to_string(index=False, header=False)) # uncomment if needed
```

Comment: Both methods are working. thanks for that.

I have another question, if i would to check for non-blank CTYPE and DTYPE fields, instead of CTYPE == 'A' and DTYPE == 'I'.

2nd method query function is working
res = table.query("INVDT == '2023-11-23' and CTYPE != '' and DTYPE != '' ")

1st method is not working. I tried below code, it is not working
records = idx.search(match=(datetime.date(2023, 1, 1), not '', "I"))

Comment: Maybe you should consider [opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new post. Otherwise, your question becomes a moving target.